# KTable-KTable Foreign-Key Join Semantics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#ktable-ktable-foreign-key-join) from Confluent website mentions the following:

> The left KTable can have multiple records which map to the same key on
> the right KTable. An update to a single left KTable entry may result
> in a single output event, provided the corresponding key exists in the
> right KTable. ***Consequently, a single update to a right KTable entry
> will result in an update for each record in the left KTable that has
> the same foreign key.***

Looking at the example below the explanation:

[image: KTable-KTable Foreign-Key Join]

According to explanation, in the case of inner join `(10, baz)` on the right side should trigger two records on the left side that will be added to resulting join table. But in the explanation it's not in the table. Is this a typo? Or I'm missing something.

Comment: From the documentation I agree that the INNER JOIN should also yield updates `(q,10,baz),(r,10,baz)` after the foreign key is created.

But maybe there's a issue somewhere when the foreign key `10` does not exist at the moment that `(q,10)` and `(r,10)` are processed, the inner join considers them dead.

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet where you are making a foreign key join between two ktables? I want to do the same but I haven't been able to implement it on my own .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's an error in the docs. -- Thanks for calling it out. We will fix it.

Btw: feel free to email to docs@confluent.io if you encounter errors in the docs so we can fix them!